Object displaces once parented to bone
i just ran in the next issue when parenting an object to a bone. It displaces by 57m and rotates it. Frustrating as hell.
And yes, before i did anything i applied scale, rotation, etc.

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks for your help.

What do you mean by "ran in the next issue" and what exactly are you trying to do? Have you watched any rigging tutorials?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
